How to inform the client that the GATT server has been closed
I'm working on an app that works alternatively as a client or as a server for GATT connections and the related data exchange.
The app has a status bar with the bluetooth connection status.
The app works fine except when the server is closed
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        if (preference_BluetoothMode == "Server")
        {
            bluetoothService!!.stopServer()
        }
        else
        {
            bluetoothService!!.disconnect()
        }
        // other
    }

    fun stopServer() {
        if (mGattServer != null) {
            mGattServer!!.close()
        }
    }

In this case the client is not informed about the new server status and consequently the status bar cannot be updated.
In particular, BluetoothGattCallback does not receive notifications.
Note that I tried, without success, to disconnect all devices from the server (before closing it), using the following function:
    fun disconnectFromGattServer() {
        devicesArrayList.forEach { device ->
            mGattServer!!.cancelConnection(device)
        }

I need to update the client's status bar with the new server status when it is closed.

It may not be an elegant solution, but it seems to work:
I inserted a disconnection message in the on Destroy function and moved the closing of the Gatt Server to the onUnbind function of the service
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        if (preference_BluetoothMode == "Server")
        {
            bluetoothService!!.sendMessageFromServer("I'M DISCONNECTING")
//            bluetoothService!!.stopServer()
        }
        else
        {
            bluetoothService!!.disconnect()
        }
        // other
        }

service
override fun onUnbind(intent: Intent?): Boolean {
    close()
    return super.onUnbind(intent)
}
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private fun close() {
    bluetoothGatt?.let { gatt ->
        gatt.close()
        bluetoothGatt = null
    }
    if (mGattServer != null) {
        mGattServer!!.close()
    }
    // other
}

